# I have been notified about a comment even if I shouldn't be

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, notifications, comment-replies

I have simply edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872338/no-results-returned-for-elseif-php-query) question and after some time, I got notification in my inbox about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872338/no-results-returned-for-elseif-php-query#comment-11088035). However, based on FAQ, last commenter with the most similar name should be notified, that means the questioner should be notified.

Both the questioner and I are called Martin. But [I edited at 18:43](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8872338/timeline), after which the other Martin (the OP) commented at 18:50. So I guess the other Martin should have been notified about wikp's 18:51 comment.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post owner is *always* notified of comments (no need for any `@` reply), so any `@Martin` is assumed to *not* be directed at them (if you weren't present, it'd even be automatically removed)...this is working as-designed.

Comment: Ah, I have forgotten this fact.

Comment: It actually wouldn't have been removed, because the OP and at least one other user had participated in the comment thread.

Comment: @Tim - In this case yes...that was more of a general statement of how things worked, not on this specific question.

Comment: Yeah, it just seems a bit weird that the system considers the OP part of the comment thread in that case (allowing the unnecessary `@mention` through for the sake of clarity), but effectively ignores them if someone else participates who has the same name. I understand it from the "They're always notified anyway" perspective, but since the autocomplete doesn't include post editors, but will bring up "Martin" as a target in this case (the "wrong" Martin), it kind of feels like there's a disconnect there.